# Ionic to signed apk with neo4j driver

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, neo4j, capacitor, neo4j-driver

I'm actually working on a Ionic projet and i'm using neo4j driver to use my neo4j database.

And i wanted to know if the connection with my database won't stop working after creating my apk

Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome! Can you add more details about what you're trying to do? What's the relation between creating an APK and the database connectivity?

Comment: i'll try to add more detail:

I have to create an app with ionic trought capacitor. And i'm using the neo4j driver to connect my database. And i wanted to know if those driver database will "transfert" in the native code created with capacitor or not